# Trying to make a post request from nodejs to php server

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, heroku, localhost

I just uploaded my nodejs app on Heroku which makes a post request on my localhost 127.0.0.1 my localhost server is on PHP which takes a file and some data and generates an invoice but the problem is I get this error in the Heroku log when my deployed node server tries to make a post request to my PHP server using Axios.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okzpq.jpg)

You can see there is a message `This is an error` ignore that because I concatenated that with the error.

I would appreciate any help thanks.:)

Comment: From the perspective of your deployed node code, 127.0.0.1 is the heroku server, not your own computer. An axios request to 127.0.0.1 will only work inside a web browser, and only if the page is accessed on the computer that also runs the PHP backend. You have to a) also host your PHP backend online b) add CORS headers so heroku is allowed to request from it

Comment: So if my PHP backend server was deployed then would it work? and also if i changed that 127 links to my deployed PHP backend server?

Comment: Yes, exactly. However, why use two separate backends in the first place?

Comment: Bro, actually I made a system where the PHP backend server tries to read a docx file text but honestly, I tried every possible solution it quit didn't work so I used mammoth in nodejs server which reads it and sends some data to laravel.